# Repeat in author names when referring to three or more authors

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, hyperref, citing, author-number

I am using the two-column format of the latex template provided by Springer( https://www.springer.com/gp/livingreviews/latex-templates ). To break longer citations I am using "breakcites" package. I use a bibtex file.

When I cite any paper with three or more authors (say author names are A,B,C with the publication year 2015), the citation comes out as:

This is the sample to show citation [A et al.(2015)A,
B, and C] which has 3 authors, [M and N(2005)] hav-
ing 2 authors, and [H(2010)] which has 1 author.

Here's the corresponding code snippet:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}          % twocolumn

\makeatletter
\def\cl@chapter{\@elt {theorem}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{moreverb}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools, cuted}
\captionsetup{compatibility = false}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{backref=true,       
    pagebackref=true,               
    hyperindex=true,                
    colorlinks=true,                
    breaklinks=true,                
    urlcolor= black,                
    linkcolor= blue,                
    bookmarks=true,                 
    bookmarksopen=false,
    citecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    citecolor=blue,
    linkbordercolor=blue
}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{breakcites}

\begin{document}
\title{TITLE OF THE ARTICLE}
\author{Tej Kumar}
\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}

This is the sample to show citation \cite{A2015} which has 3 authors, \cite{M2005} having 2 authors, and \cite{H2010} which has 1 author.

% BibTeX users please use one of
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}  
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}      % basic style, author-year citations
%\bibliographystyle{spmpsci}      % mathematics and physical sciences
%\bibliographystyle{spphys}       % APS-like style for physics
\bibliography{tempBIB}   % name your BibTeX data base

\end{document}
% end of file template.tex
```

and the BIB file:

```
@article{A2015,
abstract = {XYZ.},
author = {A and B and C},
doi = {DOI},
isbn = {1234},
issn = {5789},
journal = {someJournal3},
keywords = {keywords},
number = {1-2},
pages = {100--110},
publisher = {somePublisher3},
title = {{someTitle3}},
url = {someUrl},
volume = {1},
year = {2015}
}
@article{H2010,
abstract = {XYZ.},
author = {H},
doi = {DOI},
isbn = {1234},
issn = {5789},
journal = {someJourna2l},
keywords = {keywords},
number = {1-2},
pages = {100--110},
publisher = {somePublisher2},
title = {{someTitle2}},
url = {someUrl},
volume = {1},
year = {2010}
}
@article{M2005,
abstract = {XYZ.},
author = {M and N},
doi = {DOI},
isbn = {1234},
issn = {5789},
journal = {someJournal1},
keywords = {keywords},
number = {1-2},
pages = {100--110},
publisher = {somePublisher1},
title = {{someTitle1}},
url = {someUrl},
volume = {1},
year = {2005}
}
```

The output desired is the following:
This is the sample to show citation [A et al.(2015)] which has 3 authors, [M and N(2005)] hav-
ing 2 authors, and [H(2010)] which has 1 author.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Get yourself in our seat. In order to solve your problem, we would need to put together an example and fumble around long enough, till we actually reproduce your problem. Could take 2 minutes, could take 20 minutes, one could give up after half an hour. Please edit the question and add a minimal working example to minimize our efforts.

Comment: Seems that `spbasic` works best with `natbib`, so I suggest you load that package as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same issue and as per the comment, I used `\usepackage{natbib}` at the beginning of the document.
The issue was resolved.

Comment: Could be more specific on how this answers this question?